# Is there a way to view password stored in Windows Credentials?

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords, credentials, credentials-manager

I have a list of credentials stored in my Windows Credential Manager. But I can't view those passwords. Is there any way to see those credentials?[image]

Comment: Is there a problem or something ? Why don't you just click on the arrow?

Comment: @Devid The arrow doesn't reveal the passwords.

Answer (score 4):

You could try Network Password Recovery tool from [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html)

Comment: Tried that now. The password is not in plain text. This is what I got for each User -  



                                                                                                          

D81z8YUl,YHgArp[t12w9'$\QFgPNk%pJB`c1.feZhpouff9C:'eeGNfdlUXYFv#Fw)g"q$:KrY[gu-f6^?2jG3wUkC5|D+*WZT%dCVvlV(w!7sejK+p$wV]9Hj]bQ=xpWN%GXg3#&BH,Wx.'q7a~iGYe5b)D3MZK5;M_mUR&Rttd#J@!u_@,wD$JtlE1bvD~[;sgMet(N,$tul@$g.or*GqD@\qWbn

Comment: It depends. Some application store the password as plain text and some applications hash it.

Comment: FYI: Windows defender flags this with "This program has potentially unwanted behaviour."

Comment: @ChristopherChase Windows defender flags any program that can potentially be used by a hacker as having "potentially unwanted behaviour". This includes many legitimate tools.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows 10, just an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a developer you could take advantage of this library to find your stored Windows Credentials.
https://github.com/spolnik/Simple.CredentialsManager

Answer (score 2):

Windows has increased the security of passwords.

If you're in the "Windows Credentials" section of the Credential Manager,
and if you expand any credential using the arrow, you'll find that
asterisks are shown instead of the passwords, and I found no way to
convince Windows to show the password itself on my computer.

If you open PowerShell and attempt to get the credential of some user
using the
[Get-StoredCredential command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7.3),
Windows will ask for the password of that account, which sort of defeats
the purpose of getting the password.

To get at some of the passwords requires the Nirsoft program of
[CredentialsFileView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/credentials_file_view.html),
which can show most but not all passwords, but it requires entering
the Windows login password into the program.
I suggest sorting by the column of "Entry Type" in order to sort
by password type. The interesting ones probably have the Entry Type
of "Domain Password".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try to crack the passwords with [mimikatz](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz)(GitHub):

1. Download the ZIP file from the release page or from [here](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/releases/download/2.2.0-20220919/mimikatz_trunk.zip)
2. Place it onto C: and extract the content
3. Open powershell as an admin
4. `cd` into the folder where the executable `mimikatz.exe` is placed
5. Start mimikatz with `mimikatz.exe`
6. Run these commands:

```
privilege::debug
token::elevate
sekurlsa::logonPasswords
```

7. After these commands you get a list of credentials and there you should find your desired passwords.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Totally worked, thanks. Chrome hates mimikatz and I had to fight a bit with Kaspersky, too, but once I got all that under control it did indeed list the credential passwords.

Comment: It is a bit a pain in the ass, but happy that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single .cs file to print the password of a generic credential:
https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/Misc/blob/c2e28fb9e37b7d115bead10a0bc7bfce5e1e4375/WindowsCredentialViewer.cs

I'm not redistributing a binary since reading credentials is a dangerous thing and you should verify what you run before you download a tool from the internet to read your passwords. Just add that single C# file to a new C# console app and run.

Comment: Unfortunately "CredReadW" returns false for the password I'm trying to recover even if running the program as administrator...

Answer (score 0):

For python see the `keyring` module ([link](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/)) e.g:

```
pip install pywin32 keyring
python -c "import keyring;print(keyring.get_password('servicename', 'username'))"
```