# How do I view stored passwords in the Credential Manager?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, password-recovery, credentials, credentials-manager

In Windows 10, how do I view stored passwords in the Credential Manager?

[image]

All the search results on the internet say to press a "Show" button which, clearly, doesn't exist.

I did find [Is there a way to view password stored in Windows Credentials?](https://superuser.com/questions/803132/is-there-a-way-to-view-password-stored-in-windows-credentials) but that's about Windows 7, not 10, and none of the answers seem to apply.

Is there some way to do it in PowerShell maybe? Or another built-in GUI that can do it?

Comment: Voting to reopen as that question is about Windows 7, not Windows 10, and so the answers are very different.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.

The only way I found for now to use EaseUS Key Finder.

This is my passwords! I do not want to pay or use third party applications to view my passwords.

Please, if anyone else is know how to get the stored passwords in Windows 10, let us know.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1194274)